# Pyinstaller-can't assign to operator: opencv-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyinstaller

I am trying to turn my opencv-Python project to an exe using pyinstaller. I am using hidden imports to import the opencv-Python module but I keep getting the following error:

> File "slave.spec", line 17
> hidden_imports_opencv-python = collect_submodules('opencv-python')
> ^ SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

It looks like the "***-***" symbol is causing the error. But I have no clue how to otherwise import this module without using the actual name(or the "***-***" symbol)

Comment: `openccv-python` is a valid *directory* name, but it's not a valid *module* name. If there are no other issues, you should be able to use a name like `hidden_imports_opencv_python` instead.

Comment: Totally worked. Thank you for your quick answer!